# Remove slash before apostrophe in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress site and generated thousands of posts via a spinning script.

In the content and title, wherever there is an apostrophe, I also see a \

How do I remove all the \ before the apostrophe?

The solution should remove the slash:
Dov\'è   ->  Dov'è

What MYSQL query can I run on phpmyadmin in order to do that?

Comment: Can you post the script? Or how you select currently?

Answer (score 0):

From a pure SQL-perspective it would be like this.

```
SELECT Replace(foo, '\', '') AS foo
FROM foo
```